# Fix broken links after a file server migration

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, file-server

We have files that need to move from a old file server to new file server.there are excel documents with links to other excel documents.

But There are some broken links inside Excel Documents.  How can we fix broken links in Office documents ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Check out https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-find-fix-broken-links/ for examples of manual or VBA-based fixes. If you have a ton of files, there are a variety of tools like excel add-ons that can help automate it e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=tool+to+fix+broken+links+in+excel